# What is LDO Ishutdown?

Tags: voltage-regulator

Comparing two negative LDOs One has a Ishutdown rating of 3uA and the other 17uA. Was wondering what exactly Ishutdown is? I can't seem to find any explanation.

Comment: Where is the datasheet?

Comment: Since 'I' typically refers to current (and the units you've given are in uA) and 'shutdown' is not an obscure term - 'Ishutdown' would be the amount of current the part consumes when it is in the 'shutdown' state. Is this really all your question is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be one of 2 things.

I would think when looking at Ishutdown, it would be the max current before shutting down. However, if you look at your figures, you can see that the 'I' values are extremely low, so this seems very unlikely.

The second thing it could be is how  much current it consumes when it is in 'shutdown' This seems far more likely due to the low values.

After a quick google search for Ishutdown, I came across this [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps709.pdf). Looking at the Electical Characteristics section, we see this part:
[image]

To me, this confirms that it is my second option that is correct. The output current limit is pretty self explanatory and if you look at the conditions for the Ishutdown, you can see it says Ven = <0.4V.

As the EN pin needs the pin driven high to enable the device, this shows us that Ishutdown **must** mean the current drawn from the device when in shutdown mode.

Comment: The second option is probably correct if it's a TI regulator. Linear Tech negative regulators also quote a shutoff current, but it's the current that the REF pin needs to be starved to if you want to shut down regulator (see the LT1185). It's pretty weird, just a needlessly complicated substitute for an EN pin. I can go into further detail if the OP posts a part number.

Comment: I could only post an answer with what I had unfortunately as we do not know the part number the OP is using. Hence showing show I came to that conclusion which should hopefully make it easier to follow

Comment: Yeah, I think yours is as good a guess as we can make without a part number. I just can't resist an opportunity to highlight LTC's bizarre design choices

Comment: Yeah I have seen some stuff that has forced me to read 2 or 3 times! Lol